# GSoap QT undefined reference to `soap_new'?

Tags: gsoap

I'm trying to use gSoap in QT. When I compile my project I get:

```
undefined reference to `soap_new'
undefined reference to `soap_delete'
undefined reference to `soap_end'
undefined reference to `soap_free'
undefined reference to `soap_delete'
undefined reference to `soap_end'
undefined reference to `soap_free'
```

My sample pro contains:

```
INCLUDEPATH += ../../gsoap-2.8/gsoap/
LIBS += -lwsock32
```

Any idea what's wrong?

I produced file with:

```
soapcpp2 -I ../../gsoap-2.8/gsoap/import -i quote.h
soapcpp2 -I ../../gsoap-2.8/gsoap/import quote.h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions are defined in `sdtsoap2.c` or `stdsoap2.cpp` (depending if you are using C or C++; for Qt I infer C++).

You must either include `stdsoap2.cpp` in your project or link against `libsoap++`.

If you need to pass different flags like `WITH_NONAMESPACES`, use the first.If you have no special configuration for GSOAP, use the later.

Look at [GSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html) docs for more info.